# Receiving a null return value from a custom action

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

In testing custom actions, we built one through the native process designer UI that assigns an arbitrary value to an output argument.

However, no matter what type of output argument we use, no matter the value of input or output, we always receive a null response for that output argument.

Answer (score 2):

We had a step to stop the custom action with a status of "xucceeded" after the assign value step. Once that step was removed, everything worked fine.

Comment: Thanks for sharing.. :)